# Instantiate Nib and access its SubViews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, nib

I have a model class:

```
import UIKit

class MyModel: NSObject
{
   var str1 : String = "Test String 1"
   var str2 : String = "Test String 2"
   var str3 : String = "Test String 3"
}
```

I have an nib file with 3 labels and a swift class with outlets and func to return its nib :

```
import UIKit

class MyNibClass: UIView
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

    func instanceMyNib() -> UIView
    {
        let view =  UINib(nibName: "myNib", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

In my viewController i use this code to instatntiate my nib and add it to 
viewController view

```
import UIKit

class myViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let model : MyModel = MyModel()
        let nibClass : MyNibClass = MyNibClass()
        let viewFromNib = nibClass.instanceMyNib()
        view.addSubview(viewFromNib)
    }
}
```

And problem that i cant solve is how to change instantiated nib labels?
I read many answers on stackOverflow but i cant find clear answer.

What is the best way to connect nib-itsClass-customModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
let view =  UINib(nibName: "myNib", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

to

```
let view =  UINib(nibName: "myNib", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! MyNibClass
```

then before you add the customview you can

```
let viewFromNib = nibClass.instanceMyNib()
viewFromNib.label1.text = "anyThing"
view.addSubview(viewFromNib)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is exactly what i need!